# Looping for slicer selection working on regular pivots, but not working on power pivots

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery

All - this is in RE: Excel VBA.
I am looking for looping through slicer selection and print PDF's. my code does work for standard pivots, but it does not work when using it on PowerPivot which is what I am looking for.

Can anyone please shed some light on how to turn the below so it works in powerpivot? (slicer from power pivot source data)

```
Option Explicit

Sub ExportPDFs()

Dim sI As SlicerItem, sI2 As SlicerItem, sc As SlicerCache
Dim fname$

Set sc = ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Date")

With sc

    For Each sI In sc.SlicerItems
        If sI.HasData = True Then

        sc.ClearManualFilter

        For Each sI2 In sc.SlicerItems
            If sI.Name = sI2.Name Then sI2.Selected = True Else: sI2.Selected = False
        Next

        Debug.Print sI.Name
        fname = sI.Caption & " " & Format(Date, "MM-DD-YYYY") & " " & "Report"
        ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=fname, _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
        End If
    Next

    ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Year").ClearManualFilter
    MsgBox "Reports Saved"
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works on Power Pivot models, just change slicer name, file name rules etc to fit your needs.

This VBA will loop through your Power Pivot slicer and print the results to 
    ' PDF.
    'To get it working change slicer name and storage location in below VBA.

```
Private Sub PowerPivotLoopSlicerPrintPDF()
Dim SC As SlicerCache
Dim SL As SlicerCacheLevel
Dim SI As SlicerItem

Set SC = ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Kolonne1") 'Add slicer name 
'between " "
Set SL = SC.SlicerCacheLevels(1)

'c(ounter) is set to 1, ready to begin
c = 1


'Repeat the a loop until number of prints exceeds number of items in slicer
Do While c <= SC.SlicerCacheLevels.Item.Count + 1

'This makes sure that SI is the correct slicer. Needed for corrent file 
' name.
    For Each SI In SL.SlicerItems
        If SI.Selected = True Then
        SlicerverdiIndex = c
    Exit For
        End If
    Next SI


    'PRINT CODE
    Dim FName           As String
    Dim FPath           As String

    'Define file path for printed file storage
    FPath = "C:\Users\remia\Desktop\VBA\"   'Choose your filepath
    FName = SI.SourceName

    'Define WHAT to print and how to build file name
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
    FPath & "\" & FName & ".pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:= _
    False

    'PRINT CODE FINISHED

'Sets the slicer to the last item in the list
If SlicerverdiIndex = 1 Then
    SlicerverdiIndex = SC.SlicerCacheLevels.Item.Count + 1
End If
SC.VisibleSlicerItemsList = SL.SlicerItems(SlicerverdiIndex - 1).Name

'Adds 1 to the counter, will loop until end of slicer has been reached.
c = c + 1

Loop

End Sub
```

The following code works if you just want to loop/print the slicers WITH data:

```
'This VBA will loop through your Power Pivot slicer and print the results to PDF.
 'To get it working change slicer name and storage location in below VBA.

Private Sub PrintTimelisterPDF()
Dim sC As SlicerCache
Dim SL As SlicerCacheLevel
Dim sI As SlicerItem

  Set sC = ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_OrdreNr") 'Add slicer name between " "
  Set SL = sC.SlicerCacheLevels(1)
  Set sI = SL.SlicerItems(1)    'Sets sliceritem to a start value

  'c(ounter) is set to 1, ready to begin
  c = 1

 'Repeat the loop until the slicer doesnt have any data. "Do while c=1" is to kick it 
  off in the first place
   Do While c = 1 Or sI.HasData = True

 'This makes sure that SI is the correct slicer. Needed for corrent file name.
   For Each sI In SL.SlicerItems
 If sI.Selected = True Then
    SlicerverdiIndex = c
    Exit For
    End If
    Next sI

'Ensure that print only happens when the slicer has data
If sI.HasData = True Then


    'PRINT CODE
    Dim FName           As String
    Dim FPath           As String

    'Define file path for printed file storage
    FPath = "C:\Users\remi.ovstebo\Documents\VBA\"   'Choose your filepath
    FName = sI.SourceName

    'Define WHAT to print and how to build file name
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
    FPath & "\" & FName & ".pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:= _
    False
    'PRINT CODE FINISHED

 End If


  'Select next Value in slicer
    sC.VisibleSlicerItemsList = SL.SlicerItems(SlicerverdiIndex + 1).Name

  'Adds 1 to the counter
    c = c + 1

    Loop

    End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I posted a follow-up question; I wonder if you can take a look https://stackoverflow.com/q/57778769/10833021 - I wanted to know how to export PDF's when multiple slicers; that is, use secondary slicers to filter main slicer, and pull PDF's from main filtered main slicer.

Comment: Sorry, im not proficient enough in VBA to find the solution. I had to "brute force" and test for hours to get the first solution working :)  @LeoS.
Would be really nice to know though... I will probably need it sooner or later.